# Why am I not getting the correct contour area using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following contour:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45BJEUVEkjseFd3X3RITzM5S3c/edit?usp=sharing

containing the following points (printed in order):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45BJEUVEkjsN3NIRU5lOFBDb00/edit?usp=sharing

However, when I calculate the area of this contour (using the function contourArea), I get 157, which is too low for the size of that contour. I expect it to be in the thousands. Why is the contour area being calculated incorrectly, and how may I fix it?

The following is the code I'm using to calculate the areas of all contours of the image. The contour of interest is the last one. The original image I'm using is here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45BJEUVEkjsbGhXM3E3UW1lZWs/edit?usp=sharing

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Mat imgOriginal = imread(argv[1], 0);

  if(imgOriginal.empty())
    return -1;

  Mat img;
  resize(imgOriginal, img, Size(640, 480));

  medianBlur(img, img, 11);
  Canny(img, img, 25, 100);

  vector< vector<Point> > contours;
  findContours(img, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

  for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    cout << "Area " << i << ": " << contourArea(contours[i]) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Also, I noticed that several points in the contour are duplicates (I'm not sure why), which may be causing the area to be calculated incorrectly.

Comment: Can you paste some relevant code?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because your contour isn't closed?

**Update**: I see you're feeding it the result of a canny operation. I would try the code on an image with a very well defined closed shape to test the code and rule out a problem in the specific contour. Something like [the one used in the moments tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html#result).

Comment: I created a simple contour where I didn't close the contour (the beginning and end are not the same), and it produced the correct area. I think my problem has to do with the fact that my contour contains duplicate points. I'm not sure why this is occuring. I suppose it could be because the Canny edge itself is not "closed" in the image (perhaps that's what you meant by it not being closed).

Comment: I've updated the answer - I would try a simpler image to test the code

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [discussion](http://answers.opencv.org/question/58/area-of-a-single-pixel-object-in-opencv/#126) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Because your image has no contours but series of green pixels and a background.you need to close the contour to get contour area.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
  Mat imgOriginal = imread(argv[1], 0);

  if(imgOriginal.empty())
  return -1;

   Mat img;
   resize(imgOriginal, img, Size(640, 480));

   medianBlur(img, img, 11);
   Canny(img, img, 25, 100);

   vector< vector<Point> > contours;
   findContours(img, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cout << "Area " << ": " << contourArea(contours[1]) << endl;

    return 0;
   }
```